# SSIS 2016 VS 2015 Error 0xC001700A Version number in the package is not valid. he version number cannot be greater than current version number

Tags: dtexec, ssis-2016

I upgraded an SSIS 2008R2 package to SSIS 2016 using the upgrade wizard.  It upgraded successfully.  I do have both 2008R2 and 2016 SQL Server loaded on my server.  I am executing a batch file that calls the upgraded package.  The batch file is calling DTEXEC.exe from "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\`".  I receive these errors:

> 0xC001700A The version number in the package is not valid.  The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
>
> 0xC0016020 Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A.
>
> 0xC0010018 Error loading value ",DTS:Property xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8" from node "DTS:Property".

Any suggestions on what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to `DTEXEC.exe` in your batch file to the following

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\`

#### Detailed Explanation

The error is likely from you running the `DTEXEC.exe` from the SSIS 2008 installation folder i.e. from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS`.

The equivalent folder for SSIS 2016, if you had done the default installation, is as follows

- **32-bit SSIS**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\`
- **64-bit SSIS**: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\`

From your question, it looks like you are trying to execute the 32-bit version of DTEXEC.exe, so the right path to call it from, in your batch file is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\`

#### References:

1. [File Locations for Default and Named Instances of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547.aspx)

[image]

2. [dtexec Utility - Considerations on Computers with Side-by-Side Installations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx#side)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I received another error as soon as the package hit an OnPreExecute of a Script Task:  "0xC000F427 Description:  To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher."  From what I find on the web it is having 2 different versions (possibly an environment variable setting) on the same server.  So this answer did not fix it.  I tried rebuilding all of the Script Tasks in 2016 but still received the same error.